Nativescript Angular Tabs. Update a component's view after changing the data in another component
In a Nativescript Angular app I am using Nativescript Material Design Tabs with lazy loading.
I have a ReportsComponent showing a RadListView of Expense Reports which each contain one or more Expense items.
In a separate ExpenseComponent I have a form allowing the user to create an expense item and add it to an existing report or to create a new report.
When the user does this and clicks back to the Reports page how do I show them a refreshed listing reflecting the addition they made?
The ngOnInit in ReportsComponent calls a getReports function but it only fires once when the user logs in (when the tabs are loaded).
The tabs module tabs.module.ts has this
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: "default", component: TabsComponent, children: [

          {
            path: "home",
            outlet: "homeTab",
            component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
            loadChildren: () => import("~/home/home.module").then(m => m.HomeModule),
          },
          {
            path: "expense",
            outlet: "expenseTab",
            component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
            loadChildren: () => import("~/expense/expense.module").then(m => m.ExpenseModule),
          },
          {
            path: "journey",
            outlet: "journeyTab",
            component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
            loadChildren: () => import("~/journey/journey.module").then(m => m.JourneyModule),
          },
          {
            path: "reports",
            outlet: "reportsTab",
            component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
            loadChildren: () => import("~/reports/reports.module").then(m => m.ReportsModule),
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    TabsComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})

reports.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.getReports();
}

public getReports() {
    console.log("In getReports");
    this.updateService.getReports()
    .subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this._reports = new ObservableArray<Report>();
        this._tempreports = new ObservableArray<Report>();

        if (data["reports"] == "No Reports") {
          console.log("No Reports");
        } else {
          for (let i = 0; i < (<any>data).reportid.length; i++) {
            // load up reports
            this._tempreportnames.push(new Report(
              (<any>data).reportid[i],
              (<any>data).report_code[i],
              (<any>data).report_name[i],
              (<any>data).report_status[i],
              (<any>data).report_value[i],
              (<any>data).report_type[i],
              (<any>data).report_justification,
              (<any>data).total_business,
              (<any>data).total_private));
          }
          this._reports = this._tempreports;
          console.log("getReports this._reports="+JSON.stringify(this._reports));
        }
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log("Problems...");
      }
    });
}

public get reports(): ObservableArray<Report> {
  return this._reports;
}

And in reports.component.html I have
  <RadListView
    [items]="reports"
    selectionBehavior="Press"
  >
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">

etc

The reports list load up fine on startup.
But when I go to the ExpenseComponent form and create an expense and add it to a new report, then go to back to the list of reports, it has not updated.
How do I make this happen?
If I need data binding, how should I approach it?
I just need to make it call getReports() every time that page is visited, I think.
Thanks.
=====================================
Update (still not working)
I have been going around in circles with ChatGPT on this and have been trying to manually force Change Detection by a number of methods: ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy OnPush. Nothing is working to update the ReportsComponent view to display a report that was newly created elsewhere. The reports gets created on the backend upon submission of a form on a different ExpenseComponent. When this happens I just want to http GET the reports list from the server and essentially refresh the ReportsComponent view.
Here is some code. Nothing seems to be working to update the view. I can't see what is wrong.
In ExpenseComponent upon successful creation of an Expense and attaching to a new Report we have:
  onExpenseSuccess(data: any) {
    console.log('Expense successfully created, refreshing reports.');
    // Trigger a refresh of the reports list
    this.updateService.refreshReports();

In UpdateService we have:
  private reportCreateSource = new Subject<Report>();
  reportCreate$ = this.reportCreateSource.asObservable();

  private reportRefreshSource = new Subject<void>();
  reportRefresh$ = this.reportRefreshSource.asObservable();
...

  getReports() {
    let url = Config.apiUrl + "ns_get_reports.php";
    return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
      map(data => {
        if (!data || !data.reportid || !Array.isArray(data.reportid)) {
          throw new Error('Invalid data structure');
        }
        return data.reportid.map((id, i) => {
          let status_codes = this.displayReportStatus(data.report_status[i]);
          let status_text = status_codes[0];
          let status_class = status_codes[1];
          let disp_report_value = this.funcService.moneyFormat(Number(data.report_value[i]));

          return new Report(
            id,
            data.report_code[i] || '',
            data.report_name[i] || '',
            data.report_status[i] || '0',
            data.report_value[i] || '0.00',
            disp_report_value,
            data.report_type[i] || 'report',
            status_text,
            status_class,
            data.report_justification ? data.report_justification[i] : '',
            data.total_business ? data.total_business[i] : '',
            data.total_private ? data.total_private[i] : ''
          );
        });
      }),
      catchError(this.handleErrors)
    );
  }

  refreshReports() {
    console.log("UpdateService - Refreshing Reports");
    this.reportRefreshSource.next();
  }  

In ReportsComponent constructor are the subscriptions
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from "@angular/core";
...
@Component({
  selector: "Reports",
  providers: [UpdateService],
  templateUrl: "./reports.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./reports.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
@Injectable()
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private _reports: ObservableArray<Report> = new ObservableArray<Report>();
  private _expenses: ObservableArray<Expense>;

  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  _reportsList: Report[] = [];

  header: string;
  isLoading = false;

  disp_report_value: string;

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
...
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef
  ) {

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.updateService.reportCreate$.subscribe((report: Report) => {
        console.log("Adding new report: ", report);
        this.addReport(report);
      })
    );

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.updateService.reportRefresh$.subscribe(() => {
        console.log("Refreshing reports list");
        this.getReports();
      })
    );
  }
...
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ReportsComponent initialized');
    this.getReports();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }
  // Example method in some component or service where you want to emit a new report

  @Input()
  public get reports(): ObservableArray<Report> {
    console.log("Running reports Getter");
    return this._reports;
  }

  addReport(report: Report) {
    this._reports.push(report);
    console.log('Report added to list:', report);
    this._reports = new ObservableArray([...this._reports]);
    this.cdr.markForCheck(); // Notify Angular about the change
  }

  getReports() {
    console.log("In getReports");
    this.updateService.getReports().subscribe({
      next: (data: Report[]) => {
        console.log('Fetched data in getReports:', data);

        if (!Array.isArray(data) || data.length === 0) {
          console.log("No reports to show or data is not in expected format");
          return;
        }

        this._reports = new ObservableArray(data);
        console.log('Updated reports:', this._reports);

        this.cdr.markForCheck(); // Notify Angular about the change
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log("Problems...", this.formatError(error));
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
      }
    });
  }



And in the ReportsComponent view we have a RadListView
  <RadListView [items]="reports" selectionBehavior="Press">

I do get this output to the console:
Change detection triggered: this.updateService.reportRefresh$

And the newly created report shows up in the console from:
console.log('Updated reports:', this._reports);

But the view is not updated.
Would really appreciate some guidance! TIA
===============================================
Second Update Fixed
FYI I found the problem.
I was providing UpdateService at the ReportsComponent component level along with the AppModule it was causing multiple instances of the service, leading to inconsistent behavior.
I had AppModule:
providers: [
...
    UpdateService,
...
  ]

and ReportsComponent:
@Component({
  selector: "Reports",
  providers: [UpdateService],
  templateUrl: "./reports.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./reports.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

I removed the providers[] array from ReportsComponent.
So now we have in the ExpenseComponent success handler:
    // Trigger a refresh of the reports list
    this.updateService.refreshReports();

UpdateService:
  private reportRefreshSource = new Subject<void>();
  reportRefresh$ = this.reportRefreshSource.asObservable();
...

  getReports() {
    let url = Config.apiUrl + "ns_get_reports.php";
    return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
      map(data => {
        if (!data || !data.reportid || !Array.isArray(data.reportid)) {
          throw new Error('Invalid data structure');
        }
        return data.reportid.map((id, i) => {
          let status_codes = this.displayReportStatus(data.report_status[i]);
          let status_text = status_codes[0];
          let status_class = status_codes[1];
          let disp_report_value = this.funcService.moneyFormat(Number(data.report_value[i]));

          return new Report(
            id,
            data.report_code[i] || '',
            data.report_name[i] || '',
            data.report_status[i] || '0',
            data.report_value[i] || '0.00',
            disp_report_value,
            data.report_type[i] || 'report',
            status_text,
            status_class,
            data.report_justification ? data.report_justification[i] : '',
            data.total_business ? data.total_business[i] : '',
            data.total_private ? data.total_private[i] : ''
          );
        });
      }),
      catchError(this.handleErrors)
    );
  }

  refreshReports() {
    console.log("UpdateService - Refreshing Reports");
    this.reportRefreshSource.next();
  }  

ReportsComponent:
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ReportsComponent initialized');
    this.getReports();
    this.refreshSubscription = this.updateService.reportRefresh$.subscribe(() => {
      this.manualRefresh();
    });
  }
 ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.refreshSubscription) {
      this.refreshSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }  
...
  manualRefresh() {
    console.log('Manual refresh triggered');
    this.getReports();
  }

  getReports() {
    console.log("In getReports");
    this.updateService.getReports().subscribe({
      next: (data: Report[]) => {
        console.log('Fetched data in getReports:', data);
        if (!Array.isArray(data) || data.length === 0) {
          console.log("No reports to show or data is not in expected format");
          return;
        }
        this._reports = new ObservableArray(data);
        console.log('Updated reports:', this._reports);
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log("Problems...", error);
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }



For example you can create Subject<Report> in your UpdateService and then subscribe to it for call GetReports().
update-service.service.ts
reportCreate$: Subject<Report> = new Subject<Report>();

reports.component.ts
constructor(private updateService: UpdateService){
  this.updateService.reportCreate$.subscribe(reult => this.GetReports())}

create-report.component.ts
createReportFunction(){
  this.updateService.reportCreate$.next(report)


The last line. this.updateService.reportCreate$.next(report) . Do you mean to call that in expense.component.ts after I create an expense item? I have a member this.report but there is an error. "Type 'Report' is missing the following properties from type 'Report': body, type, url, toJSON" Thanks

You probably create new report in form. take it to this.updateService.reportCreate$.next(your-from.value). probably you need cast your-from.value to Report
